# How to find user on the basis of its ID in mongodb using java criteria query?

Tags: java, mongodb

Friends I have come across a problem of finding the user on the basis of user id . My user id is in `long` form and I am using this code to fetch user

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("user.$id").is(userId));     
        User user = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, User.class);
```

And I am using counter to set id while saving user so in DB my collection is in this form

```
 db.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "_class" : "com.domain.user.User",
    "age" : 20,
    "username" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "roles" : [
        "ROLE_USER"
    ],
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "xyz",
    "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "gender" : "male",
    "isAccountLocked" : false,
    "prefAgeFrom" : 0,
    "prefAgeTo" : 0,
    "aboutMe" : "I like to meet new people",
    "notificationNewMatch" : true,
    "notificationMessage" : true,
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-06-08T07:30:45.878Z")
}
```

So on the basis of id which is stored in NumberLong(1) form I want to get user of `id = 1`.
In present scenerio, I am getting user null on the basis of id mentioned above.
My main requirement is that I want to fetch token on the basis of user. My token stored in DB in this form

```
db.authenticationToken.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(4),
    "_class" : "com.domain.user.AuthenticationToken",
    "token" : "6db92ee4-2c23-42ee-985e-08af8e3d4f58",
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-06-10T04:47:34.434Z"),
    "user" : DBRef("users", NumberLong(1))
}
```

Can anyone help me!

Comment: have you tried using `BasicDBObject` ?

Comment: No i havn't but is it not possible with above code?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$_id`? You seem to be prefixing the name of the collection, you don't need to do that

Answer (score 0):

Doing some research over my issue i finally got the solution  , we can find the token on the basis of user id like this

```
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("user").is(userId))
    mongoTemplate.findOne(query,AuthenticationToken.class);
```